# Disable download bar 'Show All' in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Python to create some automations that download PDF files. However, this toolbar is affecting the website's functionality, causing Selenium to not locate the element. How can I disable it?

Have tried `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=DownloadUI")` and
`download.prompt_for_download": False`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.